# Webview of Android Studio doesn't show jQuery and Firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having trouble creating a webview in Android Studio. I've developed a site that connects to the Firebase database. This site has its structure dynamically created according to the images and data that you hear from Firebase. This site works normally on Google Chrome for Android phones, but the webview simply does not show anything of the structure of the site. Is the webview an extension of the android browser? What should I do?

[My website](https://segundo-ong.firebaseapp.com)

jQuery:

```
    var leitura_bd = firebase.database().ref('animais/Gato');

    leitura_bd.orderByKey().limitToLast(100).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {

    var animal = snapshot.key;
    var consulta_imagem = firebase.database().ref("animais/Gato/"+animal+"/_img/");

    consulta_imagem.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {

        let $parent = $('<div/>', {
            'class': 'div1'
        });

        let $limites = $('<div/>', {
            'class': 'borda'
        });

        let $imagem = $('<img/>', {
            'src': snapshot.val(),
            'class': 'animal',
        });


        $barra_like = $('<div/>', {
            'class': 'barra'

        });


        let $icone_like = $('<img/>', {
            'src': 'css/like.png',
            'class': 'icon_like',
            'id': animal,
            'onclick':'seleciona_animal(this.id)',
            'data-toggle':'modal', 
            'data-target':'#myModal'

        });

        $barra_like.append($icone_like);

        $limites.append($barra_like);

        $limites.append($imagem);

        $parent.append($limites).appendTo(".aqui");


    });


    });
```

WebView:

```
 WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadUrl("https://segundo-ong.firebaseapp.com/");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: Have you enabled javascript for your  WebView?

Comment: Yes, I did. But not work :(

Comment: Can you give us your code for the WebView? And what do you mean by saying it typically works on Chrome for Android?

Comment: @RyanDoherty I updated the post with the information you requested. Is the information clear or not yet?

Comment: Is http://imgur.com/R4mXTzA what you are expecting? What version of Android are you using and if it's 5.0+ check what WebView implementation you are using in dev options

Comment: Try moving `.loadUrl()` down, so that it is called last.

Comment: Chris G Yeah i thought it was that but it apparently makes no difference.

Comment: Looks like `let` is the problem. When I load the URL into a WebView, I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` pointing to line 137, which is the first use of `let` in the document's JS.

Comment: @ChrisG Huh, I'm not getting any errors from the WebView. I'm running Nougat with Chrome Stable as my WebView implementation. But the app has to be able to work on most phones so yeah go with Chis's answer

Comment: @RyanDoherty What configuration did you use for this result?

Comment: @IsaacMeneses I have Nougat using Chrome Stable as my WebView implementation but if this is something you plan on releasing you can't just support a few people so you should either use that polyfill in your site or replace let with var as Chris said.

Comment: @RyanDoherty I did work on my physical phone; I've edited my answer.

Comment: @RyanDoherty Android doesn't suport "let", so I replace it with var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ Android doesn't support `let` yet. Just replace it with `var` and it should work.

Edit:
Tested it on my Android 6.0.1 phone and loading the URL into a WebView worked. The other test was on an emulated Android 4.4.4 which didn't recognize `let`.